# pyautogui crashes whenever it clicks

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

basicly whenever I call pyautogui to click it does it but then crashes the program. here is the program:

```
import pyautogui
import time
pyautogui.click(650, 200, 10)
print("started")
while 2 == 2:
    x+1
    waittime = random.randrange(35, 40, 1)
    pyautogui.click(600, 680, waittime)
    pyautogui.click(1270, 0, 5)
    if (x % 4) == 0:
        pyautogui.click(600, 550, 4)
```

when I run it from the command prompt I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dogja\Desktop\crap\region2\scriptybob\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    pyautogui.click(650, 200, 10)
  File "C:\Users\dogja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-    packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 362, in click
    platformModule._click(x, y, 'left')
  File "C:\Users\dogja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-    packages\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py", line 437, in _click
    _sendMouseEvent(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTCLICK, x, y)
  File "C:\Users\dogja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-    packages\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py", line 480, in _sendMouseEvent
    raise ctypes.WinError()
OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: You're right.  Same thing happening here.  I think I'm using py 3.4 as well!  Except I don't get any pretty error messages.  The app just displays the crash dialog of death.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may have been being caused by the fact that the latest version of pyautogui was intended for python 3.4 when the latest is 3.5. I found that if you're running Windows, you can use win32api. To install this, run the command prompt in admin mode and cd to your python script directory and run this command:

```
pip install win32api
```

This will install win32api and its prerequisites.

Then, to make a simple click wrapper for win32api, use this function:

```
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
```

This essentially moves the cursor somewhere, presses the left mouse button down, and releases it very fast. I did not write the click snippet shown above, but I could not find where I found it first. Sorry to whoever wrote that snippet.

Comment: Yes, but how do you make a "press + drag" wrapper?  As in dragTo() of pyautogui?  Thanks!

Comment: I have been trying for a while and tell you when it works. right now it just freezes the cursor.

Comment: You mean you CAN'T get win32api to do this?  This is not good news!  I will also try to either debug the crash of pyautogui or get win32api to do the drag, and post my results.

Comment: You don't have to install win32con to change this code: win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN has the value 2 and win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP has the value 4, so you can just use those values directly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are not using the `click` function in right way. See the function definition:

> click(x=None, y=None, clicks=1, interval=0.0, button='left',
>   duration=0.0, tween=, pause=None,
>   _pause=True)

Using `pyautogui.click(650, 200, 10)` you are saying x=650, y=200 and clicks=10. I guess you want to say `pyautogui.click(650, 200, interval=10)`.