# Python: Getting Access is denied error while running pyautogui.click

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

Here's the full traceback from Shell:

```
 File "C:\Users\Sean\Documents\pyships\mouseclicker.py", line 22, in <module>
    pyautogui.click()
  File "C:\Users\Sean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 362, in click
    platformModule._click(x, y, 'left')
  File "C:\Users\Sean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py", line 437, in _click
    _sendMouseEvent(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTCLICK, x, y)
  File "C:\Users\Sean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py", line 480, in _sendMouseEvent
    raise ctypes.WinError()
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied.
```

My current bad workaround is commenting out the following lines in _pyautogui_win.py:

```
if ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError() != 0:
raise ctypes.WinError()
```

Python is running in administrator mode, not sure how to go about fixing this properly. Especially since it was working yesterday and is only throwing errors today. The weirdest part is it actually executes the click, and hangs the script after that.

The specific lines of code causing it are:

```
    pyautogui.press('d')
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.keyUp('d')
```

If anyone knows a better way of attaching a key modifier to the click that would be excellent too!

Answer (score 0):

I now have 3 workarounds:

1 Your Solution to comment out the part of _pyautogui_win.py:

2 Create an error trap that ignores specifically the WinError 5

```
def ClickFix():
    try:
        pyautogui.click()
    except PermissionError:
        pass
```

3 Make your own wrapper

pip install win32api

this will install win32api and it's prerequisites then to make a simple click wrapper for win32api use this function:

```
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
```

Thanks to [PyAutoGui click permissions error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486151/pyautogui-click-permissions-error) for #2

Thanks to [pyautogui crashes whenever it clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824324/pyautogui-crashes-whenever-it-clicks) for #3